# Ignore/use MSSQL identifier brackets from MSSQL at Maria DB 10.3

Tags: sql, mariadb

We switched our database engine for a native windows app from MSSQL to MariaDB. Unfortunately there is (only one) wrong query within the app, like this:

SELECT `EXAMPLE` FROM `MY_CATALOG` WHERE [EXAMPLEID]='123456';

It throws a syntax error, because the [ ] brackets around "EXAMPLEID" are no valid SQL here.

As I've seen, MariaDB 10.4 will implement a MSSQL mode which accept these brackets. But is there any possiblity/option to ignore this query at MariaDB 10.3 server-side to get our app working correctly? We have no access to the source code of the app itself btw ...

Any ideas? :)

Best regards

Comment: Even if you could find a way to ignore the error, would your application logic even be correct if this query failed?  Also note that in general many more things could break in going from SQL Server to MariaDB.  The best long term fix is to update your source code.

Comment: yes, everything else work as expected. it is only this query. The problem is, that the complete transaction fails because of this. We don't require the function for this query. It could result in null, but no SQL syntax error at all.

Comment: SQL Server uses brackets; MariaDB does not.  Remove the brackets.

Comment: @RickJames not possible ... please read again my problematic

Comment: File a bug report with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB 10.4 (which will become GA within next days) you can do that by setting SQL mode to MSSQL.

```
mysql> set sql_mode="MSSQL";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table t1 (a int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from t1 where [a]=1;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```